# Spoiler bug with text selection

Tags: bug, status-declined, markdown-rendering, spoilers

In a spoiler, if you select the text, a bug sometimes prevents it from disappearing (or respond to mouse-over) after you deselect the text. Sometimes selecting and deselecting again fixes this. You can try here:

> Try to select this text, then for example go left outside the question box and click to deselect. Try a couple of times.

I'm using Firefox 32.0 on Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: Not sure if that's a bug, really. I can reproduce it in Chrome, clicking in the spoiler text makes the spoiler disappear again.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, maybe, but I would expect the spoiler to disappear if I deselect the text and my mouse is not hovering the spoiler box. After all, the logic is for the text to be hidden, unless hovered over, isn't it?

Comment: There is an exception for when the text is selected, obviously. If you then mouse-out the text remains visible until deselected again, but *there is no mouse-out when you deselect by clicking outside the spoiler*.

Comment: Clicking inside the spoiler text gives the spoiler text 'focus' again, resolving the conundrum. I think this is but a corner case that isn't really worth fixing, if it is a bug at all.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, I understand why this happens (I'm a programmer too, so it's very clear). It's just a missing "check if mouse is outside box after text is deselected".

Answer (score 2):

No one loads the page with spoiler text selected.

The point of the spoiler is to not have it shown initially. Hovering/selecting mean it has been shown.

The bug, as it stands means that a hover and selection have already occurred and the spoiler text displayed.

I see no point in fixing something like this.